# import statement is not working

Tags: java, import

JVM is unable to access user-defined classes while using ***** in import statement.
My classpath is export CLASSPATH=.:/home/aksharaaaa/Documents/programs/core_java/class_java:
At first i created the Employee.java file as a package ie.,.

```
package com.durgasoft.core;

public class Employee
{

    int eid;
    String ename;
    double esal;

    public Employee(int eid1, String ename1, double esal1)
    {
        eid=eid1;
        ename=ename1;
        esal=esal1;
    }
    public void getEmployeeDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Employee Details");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println("Eno:"+eid);
        System.out.println("Ename:"+ename);
        System.out.println("ESalary"+esal);
    }
}
```

To compile this file i used the following command 'javac -d .. Employee.java' then com/durgasoft/core/Employee.class file was created at class_java folder.
then i created the file test.java in class_java folder only with the following code.

```
import com.durgasoft.core.*;

public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Employee e= new Employee(111, "viay", 3333.333);
        e.getEmployeeDetails();
    }
}
```

when i compile the test.java file then JVM is rising a following error

```
<b>test.java:5: error: constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
Employee e= new Employee(111, "viay", 3333.333);  
             ^  
required: no arguments  
found: int,String,double  
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length  
test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol  
e.getEmployeeDetails();
         ^  
symbol:  method getEmployeeDetails()  
location: variable e of type Employee 2 errors
```

If i use fully-qualified name i.e., import com.durgasoft.core.Employee; in test.java file then JVM is able to compile and run...

Comment: Any chance you have a second `Employee` class somewhere?

Comment: no it doesn't have only one Employee file is there

Comment: already i checked but i don't have

Comment: Are you sure that in there's only one Employee class in the classes folder where the compiled stuff is? You should try deleting all compiled resources and then compiling again

Comment: You could open the `Employee.class` file and check that it contains the expected constructor - look out for something like: `<init>^A^@^W(ILjava/lang/String;D)`

Comment: this worked for me.I am assumming you are in class_java folder.use javac com/durgasoft/core/Employee.java. Employee.class file will be created inside com/durgasoft/core/.Then javac test.java.This will create test.class file in class_java.Then java test.Its done.Try this.If it works for you then i would include it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you take different class from your classpath. I may happen and it's confusing. I was such situation few times and usually [JWhich](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077468/core-java/java-tip-105--mastering-the-classpath-with-jwhich.html) may help. It tells you what class you are using exactly. You can use utility or source code. It is so small and simple - I always have it in my projects and code base and use it to eliminate ambiguity.